# Sum of cubes proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Prove that for any natural number n the following equality holds:

$$ (1+2+ \ldots + n)^2 = 1^3 + 2^3 + \ldots + n^3 $$

I think it has something to do with induction?

Comment: Depending on what you already know, it could be. What did you try so far?

Comment: I know that the sum of consecutive numbers is given by n(n+1) / 2
so the square of it would be ((n(n+1))/2)^2
I'm not sure how to prove it for every number and n+1 though

Comment: Do you remember the proof for the sum of squares? The proof for the sum of cubes is quite similar.

Comment: ah yes, working it out now! So much expansion T.T

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).

Comment: Start with 1 and induct.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I've got it :)

Answer (score 7):

By induction:

for $n=1$ it works. Then, suppose it works for a $n$. Then,
$$(1+...+n+(n+1))^2=\underbrace{(1+...+n)^2}_{=1^3+...+n^3\ by\ hyp.}+2(1+...+n)(n+1)+(n+1)^2$$$$=1^3+...+n^3+(n+1)\big(2\underbrace{(1+...+n)}_{=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}+(n+1)\big)$$$$=1^3+...+n^3+(n+1)\big(n(n+1)+(n+1)\big)$$$$=1^3+...+n^3+(n+1)(n+1)(n+1)$$$$=1^3+...+n^3+(n+1)^3.$$

Q.E.D.

Comment: ah so this is induction. thank you!

Answer (score 6):

[image: Sum of cubes illustration]

Here an illustration. The surface is the square of the sum.
Prove that each added layer (in different color) is a the wanted cube and you will be done.

Answer (score 3):

This solution assumes you are allowed to use 
$$
V_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\\
V_2 = \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$$
Use the perturbation method (set the sum of cubes equal to $V_3$. Consider 
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^4
$$
then
$$
S_n + (n+1)^4 = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n}(k+1)^4 = 1+S_n + 4 \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^3 + 4 \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 +  \sum_{k=1}^{n} k +n 
$$
Obviously $S_n$ cancels out, you know $V_1$ and $V_2$, so you can get the value for $V_3$ and see that it's equal to $\frac{(n(n+1))^2}{4}$.

Comment: Hello Alex, I just ran across this problem with sum of cubes, and I wanted to solve it without using induction and your solution is amazing, but I don't understand what you did there. Do you maybe know where I could examine the method you used a bit more? Why did you use $S_n$ or sum of 4th degree members?

Comment: This is called perturbation method, i learnt it from ch2, Concrete Mathematics

Comment: I don't know if sharing love is allowed but I love you <3 Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There is another way, if you like telescoping:

Let $V_k = (k-1)*k*(k+1)*(k+2)$  and $U_k$ = Vk+1 - Vk

$U_k$ = $k*(k+1)*(k+2)*[(k+3) - (k-1)]$ = $4*k*(k+1)*(k+2)$

= $4*k^3 + 12*k^2 + 8*k$

So if you know $1+4+9+..+n^2$ you can get your sum pretty easily by summing the $U_k$ from 1 to n-1, you will get:

$V_n$ -0 = $4*S_n + 12*C_n + 8*D_n$ , where $S_n$ is the partial sum of square and $C_n$ the partial sum of the cubes, and $D_n$ the partial sum of integers

$S_n = \frac{n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)}{6}$ , $D_n = \frac{n*(n+1)}{2}$,  if you don't know their value

Comment: ah that's a bit to process...thanks though!

Comment: Don't hesitate to vote up if it was of help ;)

Comment: will do with more rep haha