# Calculating sums

Tags: summation

My maths teacher showed me something on how to calculate sums. Let's take an example:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1) = \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 + \sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}
$$

This was an easy one, but I just can't understan how to solve such sums:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (k-1)k(k+1)\tag{example 1}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(3n-2)(3n+1)}\tag{example 2}$$

Could anybody help me, please?

**I want to understand the idea of solving sums like these, so please, do not be very specific, but help me giving these and maybe some other examples.**

Comment: For $\sum k(k+1)$ the teacher maybe noted that $k(k+1)=\frac{1}{2}\left((k+1)^2-k^2   \right)$. Then we get an instant answer for the sum via telescoping.

Comment: I don't know if it's the best practice to telescope the sum, is it?

Comment: Hard to know what best practice is. It certainly works quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

The second example is orthogonal to the first, hence a different answer

$$\frac3{(3n+1)(3n-2)}=\frac{(3n+1)-(3n-2)}{(3n+1)(3n-2)}=\frac1{3n-2}-\frac1{3n+1}$$

Set a few values of $n=1,2,3,\cdots,n-2,n-1,n$ to recognize the Telescoping Series

Comment: I think there is something wrong in this formula, because the second fraction would be 1.

Comment: @Victor, How much you are getting ?

Comment: It's ok right know.

Comment: So, given your logic, the sum would be $\frac{1}{3}\sum_{k=1}^n (\frac{1}{3n-2} - \frac{1}{3n+1}) = \frac{1}{3}(1-\frac{1}{3n+1})$,  right?

Comment: @Victor, I believe the Question should be $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{(3k-2)(3k+1)}$$  Then  $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{(3k-2)(3k+1)}=\frac13\left(\frac1{3k-2}-\frac1{3k+1}\right)$$

Comment: Could we continue [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/18566/sums-calculation)?

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula).

Answer (score 2):

$$(k-1)k(k+1)=k^3-k$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n(k-1)k(k+1)=\sum_{k=1}^n(k^3-k)=\sum_{k=1}^nk^3-\sum_{k=1}^nk$$

See  [Sum of cubes proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973242/sum-of-cubes-proof) and [Proving the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292423/proving-the-sum-of-the-first-n-natural-numbers-by-induction)

Comment: See my edit, and please, be patient to explain those things briefly...

Comment: @Victor, Ideally the second example should be a different Question. See my other answer

Comment: Should I edit it again? I guess people will become upset :))

Comment: @Victor, I think, you should better leave it as it is and practise the pattern : One Question, one post in future

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your tip

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that
$$
(k-1) k  (k+1) = 6\binom {k+1}3
$$
to get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n (k-1) k  (k+1)=  6\sum_{k=1}^n \binom {k+1}3 = 6\binom{n+2}4 = \frac{(n+2)(n+1)n(n-1)}{4} 
$$

---

For the first sum, you also have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1) = 2\sum_{k=1}^n \binom {k+1}2 = 2\binom{n+2}3 = \frac{(n+2)(n+1)n}3
$$

---

For the second problem, this is a totally different beast. You should write
$$
\frac1{(3n−2)(3n+1)} = \frac 13\frac{(3n+1) - (3n-2)}{(3n−2)(3n+1)} = 
$$

and most terms telescope.